# Seder Plate According to the Vilna Gaon

Tags: product-recommendation, passover, passover-seder-hagada, vilna-gaon

The opinion of the Vilna Gaon in setting up the seder plate is that the shankbone and the egg are placed closest to the person leading the Seder, the two matzos (the Vilna Gaon did not use the third matzo) are placed in the middle, and the maror and charoses are on the other side. (The karpas is not placed on the ke'arah, and the ke'arah is only brought to the table for Yachatz, after eating the karpas.) thus, it would look like this:

[image: First line, left to right: Charoses, Maror. Second line: Two Matzos. Third line: Beytzah, Zeroa] [picture from [this English Haggada](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=CXf8QcmxCRQC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=seder%20plate%20vilna%20gaon&source=bl&ots=ew6-GC80As&sig=AHwIKYaDtSnKZ-G632Pefa5Nk_U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U2gIVZSvOJHgaN_CgsgF&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=seder%20plate%20vilna%20gaon&f=false)]

Does anyone know where i can procure a Kaarah made according the opinion of the Vilna Gaon?

Comment: You could always make one yourself, also.

Comment: Assuming you're using the standard size hand shmura (and assuming I'm understanding your diagram correctly) that's one big seder plate.

Comment: Just put all the stuff on a platter. What are you looking for? Something with labels?

Comment: @DOUBLEAA I want a nice one specially made for the seder

Comment: @Mefaresh You guys don't have nice plates you use at the Seder already? What do you eat on, Styrofoam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order one from e.g. cafepress.com using a design e.g. like this:[image] (because it would need to be big, I'd recommending getting their serving tray).

Comment: Your answer would be further improved by adding alt text for the image: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3426.